# why in linux size of directory remained same even after deletion of its files and subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash

Why in linux size of directory remained same even after deletion of its files and subdirectories ?

I have created a directory vv1 and inside it created 500 files. `ls -lrt` was showing size vv1 as 12288 follows:

```
total 12 

drwxr-xr-x 2 cms ccsrm 12288 Jan 28 12:15 vv1
```

After deletion of 500 files, it was showing the same size

```
total 12 

drwxr-xr-x 2 cms ccsrm 12288 Jan 28 12:17 vv1
```

Why?

Comment: In what filesystem? If `ext` then [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495176/108618).

Comment: yes its ext4 but i haven't got the answer in referenced link.

Comment: Which part of that answer do you need clarification on?

Comment: a directory entry of 12K is tiny. Are you worry about that much data?

Answer (score 2):

Because of performance and because in the grand scheme of things this is a trivial and pointless problem compared to other things.

In terms of performance let us work using a simpler use case. When you create a directory and add files to it, you are essentially creating a file which lists other files, the filename, file properties, creation dates and so on. Every new file adds another to that list.

Now imagine that you want to delete a single file from a list of thousands. You have two options.

1. Load the entire list, remove the entry you do not want, write the entire list back, or at least the remainder of the list.
2. Change an already existing attribute that says "this file is or is not deleted".

Option number 1 involves an unknown size read, searching through the entire contents for the entry, moving all the remaining data down by the size of that entry, and then rewriting the entire list back to disk. This may not end up in the same location as the original and other filesystem structures might have to be updated to point at the directory block. You might not have to write the entire directory, but you would have to modify and rewrite everything after the entry you changed. This would be worse for older entries and better for newer entries, resulting in an inconsistent time to delete files depending on their age.

Option number 2 can involve changing one single byte in the directory "file". It can be (essentially) seek through the directory, read the sector containing the file entry, change one byte (nothing else changes) and write that sector back where it came from. There is no uncertainty about the amount of data to read or write, no other bits of data to update.

Option 2 is faster and more efficient and, more importantly, is likely to scale better with more extreme directory sizes. Both operations have the same initial directory read operation, to seek through to the entry being deleted, but option 2 does not have a huge penalty to write the entry back and so will be faster. Deleting a large number of files using option 1 could end up writing a phenomenal amount of data on extreme sized directories, especially when it is removing "oldest first".

So most of the time designers choose option 2.

This has the benefit that file undeletion or recovery is a possibility, at least before the data blocks get reused or the directory entry gets rewritten.

But you might ask why there isn't some scheduled task that runs and "cleans up" directories. This is a problem of "do we really need to?" Eventually the entry may well get reused for a new file, meaning that an in-place change can be made similar to a delete but with a new file in the same location. When should you run the cleanup? Traversing an entire system directory structure is a pain at the best of times and doing so at an inopportune moment can make a system unusable. You can't do it at startup, as it would make the system boot time unreasonably long, nor can you delay shutdown for several minutes either. Doing it while the system is running is similarly unhelpful as it slows down disk access as other tasks read and write.

If we constantly trimmed the list then we would have to expand the list (resulting in a size change every time) each time we added a new item and means the other filesystem data needs updating.  There is more scope for poor performance, more writes than necessary, and more opportunity for directories ending up fragmented.

The simple answer is that not shrinking directories is a mixture of design choices.

1. Not doing so can mean a performance increase
2. Consistent speed for a given directory size
3. Easily reuse entries without having to modify other filesystem structures
4. Possibility for file recovery, though not guaranteed
5. The actual size on disk of directories is largely trivial compared to the files held within it.
6. The excess folder size can be removed by moving the files out of that directory and then deleting it, freeing up the space.

As such there are good reasons not to do it, it can be fixed easily if needed, and it probably isn't *that* big a deal in the first place.

That isn't to say all filesystems do this in the same way, or that this is the "best" way. This is an explanation of why those choices would be made and their impact.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77/23682)
The size that you see here does not tell you how much space the content of the directory occupies, but simply the amount of metadata needed for the directory itself, which does not change if you add or delete files.

If you want to know how much is sotred within the directory, you should use `du` instead of `ls`.